# Mips split input

Tags: mips, mars-simulator, qtspim

I am new to Mips. I want to make a calculator with MIPS. I made a research about how can I split the user input, but I could not find it.

For example, input:"567/45" I want to split and load into registers like t0=567, t1=/, t2=45.

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. You iterate over the characters in the string and divide them into groups according to the rules you've defined. It's unclear exactly what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I am having trouble with, if the input is 567/45 how can I take "567" and store in some register and "/" store in another register. In C++ I can do it with word.substring(), in MIPS what can I use similar to substring().

Comment: _"how can I take "567" and store in some register"_ You don't store strings in registers. You store them in memory, and then place the address of the string in a register when you need to pass it to some function. _"in MIPS what can I use similar to substring()"_ You'll have to implement that functionality yourself.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now. Thanks a lot! I am really new to Mips.